# PHP session on problem with Blackberry 9000

Tags: php, blackberry, session-timeout

I have a problem with the blackberry 9000 and other lower version of blackberry .
It seems that it empty your current $_SESSION each time you transfer a page.
And I have a similar problem with this guy.

**Related**

[HTTPS and php session_regenerate_id](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/HTTPS-and-php-session-regenerate-id/td-p/125562)
Similar question [PHP session_regenerate_id and Blackberry browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598690/php-session-regenerate-id-and-blackberry-browser)

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP session_regenerate_id and Blackberry browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598690/php-session-regenerate-id-and-blackberry-browser)

Comment: @michael yes possible duplicate but stil UNSOLVED.

Comment: It's not unsolved at all.  It contains an accepted answer with an explanation of Blackberry's incorrect behavior.  To be frank, you're probably wasting your time -- RIM switched to Webkit in the 6.x version of their operating system.  Many older devices (including the 9000/Bold) won't receive 6.x due to hardware limitations.  5.x (and worse, 4.x) have a limited life, and their horrible standards support makes them very poor targets for modern mobile sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible workaround would be to use the PHP ini directive `session.use_cookies` and set it to `0`. Instead of storing the session id in cookies, it will pass it around via the URL.

A couple things you will probably want to do to make it as safe as possible:

1. Only use `session.use_cookies = 0` if you detect the browser is blackberry's.
2. Only allow limited authenticated access if the user logged in while `session.use_cookies = 0`.

Because sessionId's via urls can be copy/pasted and shared--in order to reduce risk to the user don't allow changing account details or viewing sensitive information if their session is flagged as having been signed in with URL session ids turned on. Instead, make them log in again this time with URL session id's turned off. [IE, they have to login in a better browser].